# How can i get exactly 2 decimal position in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

While writing a code I came around to a difficult situation, I have a float 2.467 But I need 2.4 only not 2.5

When I use roud() function it gives 2.5

Please help me with a code that how to get 2.4 from 2.47

Comment: Did you try math.floor()?  Or just int(), which truncates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> int(2.467 * 10) / 10.0
2.4
>>> int(2.47 * 10) / 10.0
2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'decimal' module like that:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from decimal import ROUND_FLOOR
>>> from decimal import getcontext

>>> getcontext().rounding = ROUND_FLOOR
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> float(Decimal.from_float(2.467).quantize(Decimal('1.0')))
2.4
```

Documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html